# how to use image in react lazy fallback

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a loading screen with an image

Router.js file

```
const Home = lazy(() => import("../home/home"));
import { LoadingScreen } from "../_components/LoadingScreen";

<Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
</Suspense>
```

LoadingScreen.js

```
import React from "react";

export function LoadingScreen() {
  return (   
    <h1 id="testst">successfull</h1>
  );
}
```

Question is - when I simply export text it displays it, but when I export `<img>` then rather then displaying image it shows a blank page even when I managed to inspect the page during loading I even cannot see the `<img>` tag in the source

```
 import React from "react";

    export function LoadingScreen() {
      return (   
       <img src="/public/images/site-logo/main-black.png"></img>
      );
    }
```

[image]

The above snap shows the inspected code from chrome console, here I cannot see the img tag

How to use image in loading screen, Am I doing something wrong also I tried to import css same problem occurs there

Comment: What happens if you just try to show `<Loading />` component with the `<img>` only? I mean not in `<Suspense>`. Probably loading the image takes more time then the actual loading of your expected component and that's why you see a blank screen.

Comment: @norbitrial I don't think thats the case as my bundle is 4MB and the image is just 6KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is still loading but the data loading quickly and you're not able to see the image as a fallback...

so for the debugging purpose, we can set timeout around lazy HomePage like this:

```
// const HomePage = lazy(() => import("../HomePage/HomePage"))
const HomePage = lazy(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(
    () => import("../HomePage/HomePage")
  );
});
```

So, then the HomePage will take 1 second to load and in the meantime, you will see the image as a fallback

Comment: are you available on dev.to? we can do further discussions there => https://dev.to/nomangul

Comment: No I'm not available but I will join it